# AM Charts - hiding the chart scroll

Tags: amcharts

I was wondering if there is a way to properly hide the chart scroll bar.

If you look at this code pen: https://codepen.io/conormdowney/pen/XoEpJv

The very last line I have

```
var scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();
scrollbarX.series.push(series);
_chart.scrollbarX = scrollbarX;
_chart.scrollbarX.hide();
```

But if you look at the chart you will see that there is a gap at the top of the chart. That is where the scrollbar goes. If you comment out the .hide() line you will see it show there.

I want to be able to toggle that on and off but I dont want the gap there waiting for it to return. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [`disabled`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/scrollbar/#disabled_property) property to true if you want to completely hide the scrollbar and the space it takes up, e.g. `_chart.scrollbarX.disabled = true;`. Setting it to false will bring it back.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/f7cc7a5d6fea231415e4eed6a028d118?editors=0010)

Comment: Cool that works. But there is an issue. When you show the scroll now it doesnt have the chart in it. If you do not disable the scroll and load it up you see the chart data is in the scroll so you know where to zoom into. But when you disable it and then enable it again the chart data is not shown in the scroll

Comment: You mean the chart inside the scrollbar isn't visible when you toggle disabled? That's not what I'm seeing on my end. Chrome/Firefox/Edge all work. Have you cleared your cache lately? If you're still seeing the issue, which browser(s)?

Comment: Clearing the cache sorted it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your dates need to be in ascending order for it to work with a DateAxis. Your dates are descending, which can lead into issues like the scrollbar breaking. Just call reverse() on your array:

Refer [amcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73692052/5362251)